# Stream audio content to mobile website

Tags: audio, mobile, streaming, rtsp

How do I implement a mobile website that allows you to connect to a radio station providing streaming content? I don't want a mobile application.

Comment: You really, really need to include more details if you want help.  Example: What mobile platforms will you support?  Are you streaming from or to the site?  (Title says "to", question reads "from".)